# CKEditor 4.5.11 cursor moves to top on typing in IPad v 11.3.1

Tags: ipad, ckeditor

There is an issue with CKEditor v4.5.11 on iPad v11.3.1. As soon as user starts typing in (with some data in editor), cursor moves to the top and typed characters are not visible until user scrolls up to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have described looks like this one - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/498. If that is the case, you could leave your comments there (if you have anything new to add).

From what I have read this is an upstream issue (browser native issue) but the CKEditor team is trying to find some workaround for it.

Proposed semi-workarounds are: using [autogrow plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/autogrow) or [divarea plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea) (inline editor will probably work as well). In second case you are replacing internal iframe (for which issue occurs) with div element.

Comment: However issue still exists in iPad landscape mode.

Comment: Could you add a comment in Github issue so that CKEditor guys know divarea workaround doesn't work in iPad landscape mode?